# eslint doesn't warn on unsupported ecma features

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm experimenting with eslint to better understand how to use and configure it

This is the file I'm trying to lint

```js
const obj = {
  f: 'foo',
  b: 'bar',
  bz: 'baz',
}

Object.values(obj).forEach((value) => {
  console.log('value', value)
})
```

This is my `.eslint.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "node": true,
  },
}
```

With this config it complains about the use of `const`, which was introduced in es6.

So I enable es6 by updating my config file to this:

```js
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
  },
}
```

And with that I don't get any lint warnings or errors anymore. And that's a bit surprising to me, because `Object.values` wasn't added until ecmascript 2017.

Why isn't it complaining about unsupported Object methods?

Comment: Adding the `es6` env enables ES6 _syntax_ and _globals_. `Object` does exist as a global in ES6, and `Object.values` isn't _syntactically_ invalid.